# Is a question on whether someone is a "black supremacist" going to be mod-deleted? If not, why not?

Tags: discussion, moderation

The question on whether Trump was fascist was ultimately [mod-deleted](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/50426/is-donald-trump-a-fascist) because it had a positive score and perhaps it would not have been deleted had this decision been left to the community. The one whether Trump [was racist](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/39189/is-president-donald-trump-a-racist) was automatically Community-deleted though, because it had a [highly] negative score.

More recently a [question was asked whether a lesser known figure is a black supremacist](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/61821/is-kristen-clarke-a-black-supremacist). Although closed (with no mod intervention), this question presently has a positive score, so non-mods cannot (vote to) delete it. **Is this question going to be mod-deleted? If not, why not?**

(I'm **not looking for any non-mod answers** here whether the q should be deleted or not. I'm asking this in this form because a mod [asked me](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3848/why-did-the-question-is-president-donald-trump-a-racist-get-closed?noredirect=1#comment13158_3848) to do it this way.)

Comment: In the 30 minutes since I wrote the above, the q score dropped to 0 (got two more DVs). So this mq may have been premature.

Comment: "Fascist" is a notoriously squirrely term ... "Racist" isn't much better, but at least seems to have an ineffable quality (know it when you see it). Both are tossed out in impolite discourse quite frequently. "[Race] supremacist" is perhaps answerable, but the current trend in usage seems to be "racist white guy" more frequently than the old timey "X race is actually qualitatively better than all the others". For any such question, I don't see why the opinionated form "Is X a Y" should be preferred over "What is the argument for the well-known opinion that X is a Y".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I believe that the question is not appropriate in its current form and was thus correctly closed, I have decided to not yet delete it. The reason is that I believe that the question can still be salvaged into a useful question by removing the questions about whether subjective labels apply and focusing on the objective sub-questions it asks. I started a dialogue with the question author to see if we can save this question. When we can not, I am going to delete it.

Update: Unfortunately the dialog failed. The author does not agree with the edits and insists that the question should ask if a politician is a racist and prompt us to either find some dirt on them or prove a negative. So I had to delete it.

Comment: I feel that your mischaracterization of what happened is quite hostile Philipp. You claimed that "has X done Y" is a loaded question and edited the question to reflect that opinion. I disagreed and explained why I thought "there is no evidence X has done Y" is a valid answer, and edited the question to comply with everything that you told me. To say that I have "insisted" on anything is hurtful I have always followed your feedback, and to say that I am asking you to "dig dirt" when just asking for evidence is mean. And then you ask me to "prove a negative" when I just explained that is wrong.

Comment: It's upsetting to read such a rude message after trying so hard to follow your various guidelines. If you have to delete it because negativity isn't allowed, ok. But I can't express how disappointing I find your mean spirited and completely unnecessary edit to this post.